# Query for conditions across rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a table like this

```
id |   item |  price | vip
---+--------+--------+-----
0  |  tv    | 2000   | NULL
1  |  tv    | 2500   | TRUE
2  |  camera| 3000   | NULL
3  |  camera| 3500   | TRUE
4  |  phone | 1000   | NULL
5  |  pen   | 2      | NULL
```

In this table, I have some duplicated entries because I need to store vip price. If normal person visit, I need to show

```
item  | price
------+---------
tv    | 2000
camera| 3000
phone | 1000
pen   | 2
```

If vip person comes, then I should show price like

```
item  |  price
------+-----------
tv    | 2500
camera| 3500
phone | 1000
pen   | 2
```

The last column is Boolean.

I need query to get items. Please help to get the query for this.

Comment: Why both MySQL and Postgresql tags?

Comment: I am using Postgresql, but I think this is very common thing, query should be same for both type of database. I may be wrong !

Comment: Doesn't matter if the query works with other databases or not, don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @NarendraSisodiya : Do you want to show `pen` for both ?

Comment: @Ullas - yes, pen should be shown for both..

Comment: You are using tri-boolean logic (TRUE, FALSE, NULL). Is there a reason for this? What would FALSE indicate? That the price must not be shown to a VIP?

Comment: using tri-boolean logic. legacy code ! FALSE and NULL are considered as same. There is no FALSE in my database, it is only containing TRUE or NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular customer:

```
select item, price
from tablename
where vip is NULL
```

vip customer:

```
select item, price
from tablename t1
where vip is true
   or not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.item = t2.item
                    and vip is true)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a WHERE clause

```
 SELECT price from *** WHERE ((VarVip = true AND vip IS NOT NULL) OR (vip IS NULL)) and item = ...
```

I can't test it but it should print the VIP price if it exists and the normal price otherwise. If it doiesn't ( which I doubt ) you can still add a test like this in the where clause :

```
exists(SELECT price from *** where vip IS NOT NULL and item = ...)
```

Comment: No, this will not work, 'vip' column flag is not the sole criteria.

Comment: See, for printing vip prices, I need to check that for a given item vip price present or not ? If vip price present then use that price other wise use normal price..